# Mais de um valor em uma variável id

Tags: select, checkbox

Select:

```
<div class="span2" class="checks" >
   <h4>BRANCO</h4>
   <img src= "/images/cor-05.jpg"  width="57" height="27">
   <input type="checkbox" data-id="TRANSPARENTE" name="cor5" value="BRANCO"  />
   <label for="lineatura5">Lineatura<span class="required"></span></label>
   <select class="span6" name="lineatura5" id="lineatura5" value="">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
   </select> 
</div>
```

Function:

```
$('select[name="substrato_imprime"]').on('change', function(){
  $('.checks').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
  if($(this).val() !== ''){
    $('input[data-id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('checked', true);  
  }
});
```

Checkbox:

**`<input type="checkbox" data-id="TRANSPARENTE" name="cor5" value="BRANCO"  />`**

Em um campo select acima deste checkbox, tenho 4 opções:
TRANSPARENTE, FOSCO, PEROLA E METALIZADO.

Tenho uma function que se escolher a opção "TRANSPARENTE", por exemplo, este checkbox acima é marcado.
Só que preciso que as opções "FOSCO" e "METALIZADO" também aconteça essa marcação, se for escolhido no campo select.
Existe uma maneira de passar mais de um id para que a function não faça apenas da opção "TRANSPARENTE"?

PHP é a linguagem.

Comment: Você quer alterar o ID do checkbox ou você quer colocar mais de 1 ID tipo, TRANSPARENTE, FOSCO, METALIZADO?

Comment: Colocar mais de 1 ID Victor...

Comment: Coloque o código que você já tem

Comment: Código completo JrD

Comment: Por que nao cria input hiddens pra fazer esse controle? Ai no Js de mudança do item você manipula esses valores, limpando ou setando eles.

Comment: Sei o que está falando, mas não sei executar. Sou leigo ainda. Poderia mostrar como ?

Comment: Poderia, mas deixa só eu entender, qual o propósito final disso tudo??

Comment: Tenho 4 materiais a serem escolhidos no campo Select. Quando for escolhido os materiais "TRANSPARENTE", "FOSCO" OU O "METALIZADO", o checkbox da cor BRANCA deve ser marcada. Assim, meus operadores não esquecerão de fazer a solicitação desta cor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara não sei se entendi muito bem a sua questão, mas, se for só marcar o checkbox quando selecionar as opções TRANSPARENTE, FOSCO e METALIZADO no select pode fazer assim:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var textoVal = $(this).val();           // pega o value de cada option
  if(textoVal == '52' || textoVal == '42' || textoVal == '32') {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);      
  } else {
    $('input').prop('checked', false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="span2" class="checks" >
   <h4>BRANCO</h4>
   <img src= "/images/cor-05.jpg"  width="57" height="27">
   <input type="checkbox" data-id="TRANSPARENTE" name="cor5" value="BRANCO"  />
   <label for="lineatura5">Lineatura<span class="required"></span></label>
   <select class="span6" name="lineatura5" id="lineatura5" value="">
      <option value="">Selecione</option>
      <option value="52">TRANSPARENTE</option>
      <option value="42">FOSCO</option>
      <option value="32">METALIZADO</option>
      <option value="22">PÉROLA</option>
   </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isto !!!

Comment: Se tem vários outros checkbox, ele marca também. Como determinar que somente os que quero sejam marcados ?

Comment: Várias formas, dar um **id** para cada checkbox, dar um **name** para cada checkbox e chamar assim `$('input[name='check1']').prop...`, pode pegar o check pelo pai que é a div e chamar assim `$('.checks > input')` que só vai pegar o check que estiver dentro da div com a classe **checks** e por aí vai.

Comment: Havia imaginado e fiz isso... Deu super certo ;-)

Comment: Jóia man :). Só mais uma observação que notei agora no código. você está chamando dois atributos **class** no mesmo elemento aqui `<div class="span2" class="checks" >`, quando o correto seria assim `<div class="span2 checks" >`

Comment: Valeu pela dica